# Use OkHttp to download lots of images to sd card

Tags: android, image, performance, okhttp

So a part of my app downloads a large number (~1600) of images to SdCard using an IntentService. I previously used Glide, but now want to switch to OkHttp, since it seems to be faster and less battery consuming. This is my current code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1600; i++) {
        try {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(imageUrls[i])
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            File testDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
                                                                  + "/downloadTest");
            if (!testDirectory.exists())
                 testDirectory.mkdirs();
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(testDirectory, 
                                                          "testImage" + i + ".png"));
            InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0)
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Is there any way I could optimize this code to make downloading faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Okio](https://github.com/square/okio) instead of `InputStream`/`OutputStream` to save some copies. Something like this:

```
BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(new File(testDirectory, "testImage" + i + ".png")));
sink.writeAll(response.body().source());
sink.close();
response.body().close();
```

See [this post](https://corner.squareup.com/2014/04/okio.html) for an explanation of why this is faster.

Comment: the link doesn't work anymore.. this one does https://developer.squareup.com/blog/buffering-data-with-okio

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is:

```
InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

and save the bitmap as jpg:

```
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be inefficient to decode the bitmap just to compress it again aftwerwards?

Comment: Somewhere you need to get the Bitmap.
If you want to make the download faster you can use multiple AsyncTasks. I hope I can help you. :)